# How to replace cartridge for this tub valve?

Tags: faucet, bathtub, plumbing-fixture

[image: mystery tub vavle]

I need to replace the hot water cartridge on my jacuzzi tub.  This is all I have access to -- I can't get to the other side.  I can't tell how to disassemble this valve to get the cartridge out... any ideas?  I can't figure out the manufacturer either since there are no markings.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The valve cartridge is threaded into the valve body. The valve body stops at the top of those visible threads in your photo. That is also where the valve cartridge begins.

Get a wrench on the flats of the valve cartridge and turn CCW. Don't use an adjustable wrench if you can help it. Use a fixed box wrench if you have the right size. Brass is soft!

*I would really try and remove the valve body from the jacuzzi first to eliminate any risk of damaging the jacuzzi.* By leaving it in place and turning CCW on the valve cartridge you'll be tightening the valve body against the tub and things could break... There has to be a way to get it out - how was it installed? If you can get it out hold the valve body with a pipe wrench and unthread the valve cartridge from it as described.

Answer (score 0):

It's threaded, there are also flats on the top of the threaded section, that allow you to use a pair of pliers or a wrench to remove it. Unscrew like normal and do your repairs. Be sure the water is turned off first though.

Comment: Thanks!  Are you saying the threaded section screws into whatever is on the underside of the tub? I'm not sure how to get a grip on that to unscrew the threaded section.

Comment: Shouldn't be. The valve body should stay attached to the tub and the valve should come out.

Comment: It looks to me like this stem *might* come out differently from the normal types. It might be that the stem unscrews at the fluted handle end probably ccw. The flats on the valve body might be there to hold the valve body while tightening the flat hold nut or while unscrewing the stem.

Comment: It is indeed hard to tell. He may just have to try until it comes out. Either way, he should not need access to the underside of the tub.